# What does "It didn't quite. Nothing can." mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From "The Long Goodbye" by Raymond Chandler:

> There was a girl beside him. Her hair was a lovely shade of dark red and she had a distant smile on her lips and over her shoulders she had a blue mink that almost made the Rolls-Royce look like just another automobile. **It didn't quite. Nothing can.**

Comment: The novel is called **The Long Goodbye**; the last word ends with a 'e'.

Comment: In these elliptical phrasings, you have to try and figure out what they go with. This is not always easy since you need to have your auxiliaries firmly in hand.

Answer (score 4):

It didn't quite *make the Rolls-Royce look like just another automobile.* Nothing can *make the Rolls-Royce look like just another automobile*.

Comment: To make something look like something else. To not quite make something look like something else. I just think spelling it out simply helps.